# Bridging two virtual machines on difference bridges

Tags: kvm, qemu, bridge, veth

I have two VMs: `vm1` & `vm2`. The host and VMs both are Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Each VM "connects" to a bridge which connects to a virtual ethernet interface and end up at `eth0` i.e.

`vm1 (192.168.0.23) -> br1 (192.168.0.1) -> veth0 -> eth0`

`vm2 (192.168.0.24) -> br2 (192.168.0.2) -> veth2 -> eth0`

Problem: Inside `vm1` I can ping `br1` but inside `vm2` I cannot ping `br2`. In fact I can also ping `br2` inside `vm1`.

I am unable to find any reason for this. Please help.

Comment: Why don't you connect them to the same bridge? Having the two VM's and two bridges on the same subnet may also cause routing problems. Try changing the third octect for vm2/br2 to 1.

Comment: @RobertJacobs Thanks! Bridging is not my final goal. I shall be adding these two bridges to two separate mininet switches.

Comment: @RobertJacobs It did solve the problem I mentioned above. Please add this as an answer so that I can accept. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having the two VM's and two bridges on the same subnet may also cause routing problems. Try changing the third octect for vm2/br2 to 1.